# How to select all of this text Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to retrieve all of the text in this box. The part number I'm trying to read is actually `148474-1`. However when I read from it I only get `148474`.

HTML:

```
<div class="SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-PartNumber-Label" style="width: 10%;">
    <p>
        <span class="SE-PartSearchResult-selected">148474</span>-1
    </p>
</div>
```

Code:

```
// This is the one without an Alias
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
IList<IWebElement> partNumbers =
    driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("SE-PartSearchResult-selected"));
partNumberWithoutAlias = partNumbers[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the first part, so just fetch the second part and concatenate both of them.

```
string firstPart = partNumberWithoutAlias = partNumbers[0].Text;
string secondPart = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-PartNumber-Label"))[0].FindElements(By.TagName("p"))[0].Text;

string allText = firstPart + secondPart;
```

Note: You should check if class- `SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-PartNumber-Label` is used once or more than once, and depending on that fetch the correct one by the index position.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you do this?

```html
<div class="SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-PartNumber-Label" style="width: 10%;">
    <p>
        <span class="SE-PartSearchResult-selected">148474-1</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Set `-1` inside `<span>`.

Comment: This is on a website that doesn't belong to me. I would if I could. I have never ever seen this before.

Comment: And could you get `Parent` on `By.ClassName("SE-PartSearchResult-selected")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code-

```
IList<IWebElement> partNumbers = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-PartNumber-Label"));
partNumberWithoutAlias = partNumbers[0].Text;
```